# Программа Клиент-Сервер

Tags: c#, .net, сокет, клиент-сервер

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста с логикой. Я хочу написать программу по типу клиент-сервер, но не понимаю как сделать так чтобы сервер отправлял ОПРЕДЕЛЁННОМУ клиенту данные, вот допустим есть 1 сервер, и 3 клиента, 1 клиенту надо отправить Привет, второму Пока и третьему ГудБай, как можно вывести "список" клиентов чтобы можно было отправлять определённым  клиентам определённые данные. Пишу на C#.NET 4.5, если можно то небольшой пример.

Answer (score 1):

Вот [очень хорошая статья по сетевому программированию](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd335942.aspx)

Вообще, как и описано в статье выше, я использую такой метод: при аксепте сокета клиента, заношу данные о нём в лист сокетов, после чего у тебя наглядный список подключенных клиентов и возможность посылать на любой из них в любой момент времени.